# Calling Collections.sort via JNI

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I am working on a JNI implementation using C and try to sort a list of type `java/lang/List` using `java/util/Collections` `sort` method with a `Comparator`. To get the descriptor signatures I mainly use `javap`.

In this case javap does not show any descriptor for the sort methods. All I get is

```
$ javap -s -p java.util.Collections | grep -i sort
public static <T extends java.lang.Comparable<? super T>> void sort(java.util.List<T>);
public static <T> void sort(java.util.List<T>, java.util.Comparator<? super T>);
...
```

In the JNI code, I use

```
// Get Collections class
jclass collections_clazz = (*(px->env))->FindClass(px->env, "java/util/Collections");
if (!collections_clazz) ...

// Get sort method
jmethodID sort_mid = (*(px->env))->GetStaticMethodID(px->env, collections_clazz, 
    "sort", "(Ljava/lang/List;Ljava/util/Comparator;)V");
if (!sort_mid) ...
```

In my case `sort_mid` is false (or NULL). The signature I use with GetStaticMethodID is a rough guess. I have to admit I am not deep into Java, but its enough to use with JNI though.

I am using `jdk1.8.0_31` with this project.

Could anybody give me a hint whats the issue here? What I am missing?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `java.util.List` != `java/lang/List` ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: *Facepalm* .. Yes, that was it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps confusingly, standard classes like `List` are not in `java.lang` or even `java.collections` but `java.util`

You need `Ljava/util/List`